# PostgreSQL update row based on the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I would update row based on the same table. Copy column "data" to every row where data is "" (empty). "Key" in this rows is the same.

```
    id |data |key 
   ----|-----|-----
    1  | xyz |key1
   ----|-----|-----
    2  | ""  |key1
```

I've tried something like that, but "relation a does not exists":

```
UPDATE a
SET a.data = b.data
FROM table a
  INNER JOIN table b
    ON (a.key = b.key)
WHERE b.data != '""'
```

Answer (score 22):

In Postgres SQL, you should not repeat the name of the target table in the FROM clause (so you cannot use a JOIN)

---

```
UPDATE table_a dst   -- <<-- target table
SET data = src.data  -- <<-- no table-alias on the lValue; correlation name is implicit here
FROM table_a src     -- <<--- same table, different alias
WHERE dst.key = src.key
AND dst.data = '""'
AND src.data <> '""'
        ;
```

Comment: definitely, this is it!

Answer (score 5):

In Postgres, the syntax is:

```
UPDATE a
    SET a.data = b.data
    FROM a b
    WHERE a.key = b.key AND b.data <> '""' AND a.data = '""';
```

Note:  This assumes that `a` is the table name; `b` is then an alias for the table and the "join" conditions are in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using subquery, for both updating from/to same table or different table.

```
 update table_name set column_name = (select column_name from table_name where id=13) where id=14;
```